# Where does a circle of radius R and center (A,A) intersect X axis.

Tags: geometry

Where does a circle centered at (A,A) with radius R >= A intersect the X axis. (This is for a machining problem.)

Comment: Use Pythagoras theorem, and make a figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C$ be the circle, centered at $(a,a)$, with radius $r$, where $r \ge a >0$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;&(x,0)\;\text{is on}\,C&&\\[6pt]
\iff\; &(x-a)^2+(0-a)^2=r^2
&&\text{[by the distance formula]}\\[6pt]
\iff\; &x^2 - 2ax + 2a^2 = r^2&&\\[6pt]
\iff\; &x^2 - 2ax + a^2 = r^2-a^2&&\\[6pt]
\iff\; &(x-a)^2 = r^2-a^2&&\\[6pt]
\iff\; &x-a = \pm \sqrt{r^2-a^2}&&\\[6pt]
\iff\; &x =a \pm \sqrt{r^2-a^2}&&\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Given that the circle has center $(A,A)$ and a radius of $R \geq A$. The formula of the cicle is given by $(x-A)^2 + (y-A)^2 = R^2$. It intersects the $x$-axis when $y = 0$, so
$(x-A)^2 + A^2 = R^2$ implies that $x = \pm \sqrt{R^2 - A^2} + A$. 
You could say that $R = A + l$, with $l$ a positive real number, then it follows, by substitution that $x = \pm\sqrt{(2A+l)l} + A$